# Брать данные JSON из URL

Tags: php, json, get

Есть кусок кода, ну никак не хочет работать, ничего не выводит.

```html
 <?php
 $json_url = "https://vils192.amocrm.ru/api/v2/leads";
 $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
 $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($data);
 echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Подозреваю что дело в одинарной ковычке перед урлом

Comment: Нет, дело не в кавычке

Comment: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://vils192.amocrm.ru/api/v2/leads): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized    
    
Если система требует авторизации, то **file_get_contents** точно не вариант. Вероятно, нужно отправлять заголовки, поэтому используй cURL.

Comment: Лучше использовать CURL, там можно и проверку сертификата отключить, и тело ответа достать даже для 401й ошибки, которое для нас {
    "response": {
        "error": "Неверный логин или пароль",
        "error_code": "110",
        "ip": "*.*.*.*",
        "domain": "vils192.amocrm.ru",
        "server_time": 1532418963
    }
}